# a code to output largest number from array

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this basic code, confident it was going to work. I see think it should work but for some reason it hasn't lol I was wondering if you guys can tell me what i did wrong. 
This is just a code to output the largest amount in  an array. I have already created the array.

```
    int index = array.length -1;
    int i, n, largest;

    largest = array[0];


    for(i=0;i < index;i++)
        if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
            largest = array[i];
               System.out.println(array[i]);
```

Any help on what i did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compare each element to the current largest element (not to the next element) :

```
for(i=0;i < array.length;i++)
    if(array[i] > largest)
        largest = array[i];
```

And after the loop you probably want to print the largest number :

```
System.out.println(largest);
```